# persian language processing prolog

Tags: prolog, expert-system

This is my prolog code, which gave me the following error:

> ERROR: Out of global stack

```
hasA(S,A):- name(S,L1),
            compar(L1,A).
compar([H1,H2|T1],T1):- H1 == 1575, H2 == 1740.

neda(H,A):- hasA(H,Z1),
            append(A,[1575,1740],A),
            state(Z1,Z2),
            append(A,Z2,A).
state([H|T],T):- H == 32.
state(A,A).
```

What is wrong? Can you help me with it?

Comment: What ths code have to do exactly ?

Comment: I don't see where you have a recursion, so perhaps this isn't all of your pertinent code? You should show what query you call that causes the stack error. `append(A, [1575,1740], A)` will always fails since a list, `A`, with `[1575, 1740]` appended to it, can't give you the same list, `A` back again. Likewise, `append(A, Z2, A)` will always fail unless `Z2` is the empty list (`[]`).

Comment: @lurker: name/2 it's the obsolete version of atom_codes/2

Comment: @CapelliC thank you. I'll remove that part of my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you call `neda(H,A)` with `A` being a free variable you end up calling `append(A,[1575,1740],A)` with `A` being a free variable as well. However, traditionally, `append` is implemented as

```
append([],Ys,Ys).
append([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]) :- append(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

Unification of `append(A,[1575,1740],A)` with `append([],Ys,Ys)` fails since it requires `A` to be `[]`, on the one hand, and `[1575,1740]`, on the other hand. Hence, Prolog tries to unify `append(A,[1575,1740],A)` with `append([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs])` and succeeds with `{A/[X|Xs], Ys/[1575,1740], Xs/Zs}` which leads to the call `append(Xs,[1575,1740],Xs)` and the process repeats, i.e., Prolog enters an infinite recursion and ultimately runs out of stack.

If I *guess* your intention correctly, you *first* would like to append `[1575,1740]` to `A` and *then* to append `Z2`. This would mean that you need to introduce two new variables, say `A1` and `A2`, to record the state of `A` after each appending step:

```
neda(H,A):- hasA(H,Z1),
            append(A,[1575,1740],A1),
            state(Z1,Z2),
            append(A1,Z2,A2).
```

Beware, however, that with `A` being a free variable on backtracking this code will generate lists of increasing length; is this what you want?